# Is there a way to see the reason someone flagged a question for re-open?

Tags: support

I went to review posts, and this question was flagged for reopen:
https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/3706

When I entered the question I tried to find the reason for reopening. When I flagged questions for reopen, I was prompted to write the reason for the flag, so I know that the (must) exists, but I couldn't see it here.

Is the reasoning for the request view-able by non moderators?
Or maybe the reason is usually seen, but this flag didn't have any reasoning attached to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no flag here involved, just a reopen vote by a 3k+ user. There are no specific reopen flags, you can only use a custom flag and write that the question should be reopened. For a closed question to land in the reopen review queue, at least one 3k+ user has to vote to reopen the question. Reopen votes have no reason attached to them, they are just a simple vote.

Comment: @ilya he's saying that no reason is given for reopen votes, so basically you are seeing everything already :-)

Comment: @IlyaMelamed re-open votes don't have a reason because they are refuting the close votes, and the reason is listed in the close message